# MS ACCESS - VBA - SHAPES THAT DISPLAY DATA

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-access

first time asking stack a question instead of benefiting from its existence.

I want to write an application using MS Access that allows the user to instantiate shapes with empty fields (text, list, combobox, radio buttons) to design their Project Management workflow. Once I write this I make it into a web application using our database to run the algorithm to guess how much time and money they'll spend on their project by task/time/money etc.

What I want to know about the MS Access shapes is if they can sustain this type of User Interface where a user can input information as an attribute of the shape, or if the shape can have attributes that are themselves text fields, lists, comboboxes and buttons. Would I be able to select through shapes or will I have to organize the controls a different way to get them into groups for the algorithm to use their data as inputs?

Is there a smarter way of doing this? I was going to write it in python but having to go through all of the nonsense with storing the data separately and going through excel and http stuff seemed more of a timesuck than its worth. This will eventually be a web application.

Thanks stack!

Comment: MS Access shapes? I'm never heard about them... What you mean? MS Access has got forms, reports, queries, etc. Please, be more specific and provide more details.

Comment: VBA is capable of producing shapes with built in Draw methods to create circles lines and squares. The problem I'm having is to know whether I can fix data to these shapes both as objects with affixed data and visual items in a work space on the desktop.

Comment: thank you for explanation. No, shapes (circles, squares) can not store data as forms and/or reports do.